# Export files from S3 to another cloud storage using Amazon Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-transfer, aws-lambda, cloud-storage

I want to add an export functionality to transfer some data from S3 to another selected cloud storage by the user.

I am already doing it by using a simple node.js server on an amazon  t2.micro instance that gets the file from S3 and pipes it to a POST request to the desired cloud storage.

The problem with this solution is scalability and network saturation of my amazon infrastructure.

I recently discovered Amazon Lambda and thought it would be the perfect solution for my feature, but then I saw that the function can't run more than 300s and some of my files may take more than 300s.

I know there are some services like mover.io which handle that, but they don't support some of the cloud storage I need to export to.

What do you suggest me ?

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to give it a shot and see how it performs in Lambda, since those functions run in a separate network space not using any of "your" AWS infrastructure.  The available bandwidth is likely different, though I can't speculate how different.

Comment: That is exactly why I want to use Lambda, the only problem I see is the time limit. The function in Lambda will not run more than 300s by default but I don't know if we can do something about it. (I asked about that in the AWS forum).